Box not rotated at the right position
in shift + mouse rotation mode, when my mouse rotate to 0 degree, it automatically rotates back to the previously rotated angle.
This only happens when it is rotated to 0 degree while holding the shift + mouse key, after releasing or rotated to other angle  everything is working fine. During normal rotation mode, there is no such issue and I tried various ways to solve this but the issue just persists
rotHandler($event: MouseEvent) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    /**
     * First calculate center of Bbox on screen
     * Calculate the offset between mouse position to center
     * use atan to calculate the angle denoted with ++ 
     * offset the angle to get real theta starting from 
     * center top counter-clockwise. 
     * 
     *              +ve
     *               │
     *    Quadrant 4 │  Quadrant 1
     *               │
     *          \    │    /
     *           \   │   /
     *            \  │  /
     *            +\ │ /+
     *            ++\│/++
     * -ve───────────┼──────────────+ve
     *            ++/│\++
     *            +/ │ \+
     *            /  │  \
     *           /   │   \
     *          /    │    \
     *               │
     *    Quadrant 3 │  Quadrant 2
     *               │
     *              -ve
     */ 
    const offsetX = $event.x - this.oriX;
    // y-axis is flipped on browser
    const offsetY = this.oriY - $event.y;
    const degree = Math.abs(this.radToDeg(Math.atan(offsetY / offsetX)));

    let r = 0;
    if ( offsetX > 0 && offsetY > 0 ) {
        // quadrant 1
        r = 270 + degree;
    } else if ( offsetX > 0 && offsetY < 0 ) {
        // quadrant 2
        r = 270 - degree;
    } else if ( offsetX < 0 && offsetY < 0 ) {
        // quadrant 3
        r = 90 + degree;
    } else if ( offsetX < 0 && offsetY > 0 ) {
        // quadrant 4
        r = 90 - degree;
    } 

    if ($event.shiftKey){
        this.deltaT = Math.ceil(r/5)*5;
    } else {
        this.deltaT = r;
    }

    this.deltaT += this.orientation;
    this.deltaT %= 360;

    this.ruler.display(null, null, +this.deltaT.toFixed(1));
}
rot($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    const offsetX = $event.x - this.oriX;
    // y-axis is flipped on browser
    const offsetY = this.oriY - $event.y;
    const degree = Math.abs(this.radToDeg(Math.atan(offsetY / offsetX)));

    let r = 0;
    if ( offsetX > 0 && offsetY > 0 ) {
        // quadrant 1
        r = 270 + degree;
    } else if ( offsetX > 0 && offsetY < 0 ) {
        // quadrant 2
        r = 270 - degree;
    } else if ( offsetX < 0 && offsetY < 0 ) {
        // quadrant 3
        r = 90 + degree;
    } else if ( offsetX < 0 && offsetY > 0 ) {
        // quadrant 4
        r = 90 - degree;
    } 

    if ($event.shiftKey){
        this.theta = Math.ceil(r/5)*5;
    } else {
        this.theta = r;
    }
    this.theta += this.orientation;
    this.theta %= 360;

    this.update();
}

HTML code:
    <!-- Rotation Handler -->
<svg:circle *ngIf="allowRotate" 
        style="cursor: grab"
        app-box-rotate
        [attr.r]="(10/scale)/2" 
        [x]="x + deltaX"
        [y]="y + deltaY"
        [w]="w + deltaW"
        [h]="h + deltaH"
        [theta]="deltaT || theta"
        [attr.fill]="color"
        stroke="white"
        [attr.stroke-width]="1/scale"
        (startDrag)="startRot($event)"
        (moveDrag)="rotHandler($event)"
        (endDrag)="rot($event)"
        (dblclick)="rot90()"
        [voltaDraggable]="edit"
        [voltaDraggableStop]="true">
</svg:circle>


As you can see in the picture, my mouse is pointing at 90 degree but the box has been automatically rotated back to its previously placed position.

What is the variable you use in  your [attr.rotation]="variable"in your SVG?
